# 7zip: How to exclude file types?

Tags: command-line, archive, 7zip, wildcards

I want to exclude the following file types:

- epub
- pdf
- html (upper case too)
- azw3
- mobi
- opf
- txt

I have this so far which doesn't seem to work, i get an error saying "Incorrect Command Line".

```
7z e "-x!*.epub" "-x!*.pdf" "-x!*.html" "-x!*.azw3" "-x!*.mobi" "-x!*.txt" "-x!*.HTML" "-x!*.opf" *
```

I also tried the above command without double quotes.

I created the above command using info from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/185135/7zip-add-to-archive-how-to-exclude-certain-file-types-extensions) (for windows) but it doesn't seem to work under Linux.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`7z` only accepts a single archive within its arguments, but you're passing a wildcard, which expands to the full content of the current working directory. Another issue is that the wildcards within the arguments will expand as well, either if non-quoted or double-quoted.

So you should only extract a single archive per command. You should remove the wildcard at the end, specify a single archive and single-quote the arguments:

```
7z e '-x!*.epub' '-x!*.pdf' '-x!*.html' '-x!*.azw3' '-x!*.mobi' '-x!*.txt' '-x!*.HTML' '-x!*.opf' archive.7z
```

To extract multiple archives at once, however, you can use multiple methods:

- `bash`:

  ```bsh
  for archive in *.7z; do 7z e '-x!*.epub' '-x!*.pdf' '-x!*.html' '-x!*.azw3' '-x!*.mobi' '-x!*.txt' '-x!*.HTML' '-x!*.opf' "$archive"; done
  ```
- `find`:

  ```bsh
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.7z" -exec 7z e '-x!*.epub' '-x!*.pdf' '-x!*.html' '-x!*.azw3' '-x!*.mobi' '-x!*.txt' '-x!*.HTML' '-x!*.opf' {} \;
  ```

Answer (score 15):

From `man 7z`:

```
-x[r[-|0]]]{@listfile|!wildcard}
              Exclude filenames
```

To exclude files (or types) you can use the following command:

```
7z a -xr@exclude.txt backup.7z /whatever/dirs/or/files
```

Notice the use of `-xr` instead of `-x`. The `r` indicates recursive so it can match excluded files in deep folder hierarchies

The `exclude.txt` file is a list of files or file types, separated by carriage returns, like this:

```
*.epub
*.pdf
*.html 
*.HTML
*.azw3
*.mobi
*.opf
*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe extracting from multiple archives wasn't possible at the time of the question.

As of 2020, `7z` **can** extract from multiple archives , but you need to specify them with a special flag:

```
       -ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}
              Include archives
```

<sub>[docs](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/ar_include.htm)</sub>

Note that when you use this you no longer need to specify the `archive_name` on the command line (where you passed `*`), so you [need to disable it](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/ar_no.htm) with the `-an` flag.

The rest of your flags work as you put them, with the exception of the quotes: they are necessary to avoid interpretation of `!` and `*` by your shell. In bash, double quotes (`".."`) still allow expansions, so need to use single quotes (`'...'`). The alternative is to escape these characters, e.g. `-x\!\*.html`.

So your command becomes:

```
7z e -an '-ai!*' '-x!*.epub' '-x!*.pdf' '-x!*.html' '-x!*.azw3' '-x!*.mobi' '-x!*.txt' '-x!*.HTML' '-x!*.opf'
```

---

My recommendation is to make the inclusion flag a bit more specific than `*`, because it will select all the files in the directory. And since you used the `e` command (not `x`) and you did not specify an output directory (with `-o` flag), the current directory will be populated with all the files from your archive. This means that if you run the same command again, the `*` selector will now select not only the archives, but also all the extracted files.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to exclude the full directory (you may have this extension file separated in directory)

```
 7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on ~/bkpFile_$(date +"%d_%b_%Y").1.7z /home/ubuntu/projectfile -mx0 '-xr!vendor' '-xr!view' '-xr!documents'
```

Here, ***vendor*** , ***view***, and ***documents*** directory has been excluded.

Comment: Why `sudo`? And what does this add to the existing answers?